# How to filter through model?

Tags: mongodb, filter, has-many-through, loopbackjs, strongloop

Assuming the standard example of physicians and patiens used by StrongLoop (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations):

common/models/physician.json

```
{
  "name": "Physician",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "patients": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Patient",
      "foreignKey": "patientId",
      "through": "Appointment"
    },
```

common/models/patient.json

```
{  
  "name": "Patient",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "physicans": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Physician",
      "foreignKey": "physicianId",
      "through": "Appointment"
    },
```

common/models/appointment.json

```
{  
  "name": "Appointment",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "appointmentDate": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "physician": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Physician",
      "foreignKey": "physicianId"
    },
    "patient": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Patient",
      "foreignKey": "patientId"
    },
```

how can I get patient from physician filtering by appointmentDate?

I tried to use something like this:

```
Physician.findOne({
    "where": {"id": physId},
    "include": {
        "relation": "patients",
        "scope": {
            "where": {
                "appointmentDate": { "gt": fixedDate }
            }
        }
    }
}, callback);
```

but it seems that Loopback look for appointmentDate on Patient model instead of on Appointment model.

Some useful hint?
Thanks!

Comment: You should check out mongoose :) http://mongoosejs.com Also note that relations inside MongoDB are not ideal so you might want to rethink your database models :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you may have something wrong in your mongo query understanding.

The operators in mongo must in the beginning of '$', so your **gt** should change to **$gt**, **where** should change to **$where**

To get patient from physician filtering by appointmentDate, we can do it by 2 steps, suppose you have the id(physId) of a specific physician.

```
var appointments = Appointment.find({
  "relation.physician.foreignKey": physId,
  "properties.appointmentDate": { $gt: fixedDate }
});  // get all appointments after fixedDate
var patients = [];
appointments.forEach(function(appoint) {
  patients.push(appoint.relation.patient);
})

return patient;  // all patients in appointments
```

**in node API**
I have read the find method in doc, it use where filter to match value of specific field, but I think it is similar as the origin :-)

```
Appointment.find({
  "relation.physician.foreignKey": physId,
  "properties.appointmentDate": { gt: fixedDate }
})
```

and then you can use some method like _.forEach(underscore.js)to get the patients from the result

I wish it can solve your problem;

Comment: About the $, it is not in loopback definition. (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter).

Comment: Well, I think it's API, query and operators have some little different from the original mongo, but the query is similar

Comment: Your solution not seems to work properly in Loopback. In any case, I managed in a similar way... I looked for all the appointments with a particular date and then look for physician connected to that appointment. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The question is not about mongo, but about loopback, mongo is simply the connector used. The connector may bring limitations but the API is the same for all connectors. I have the same question, the "through model" is documented with additional fields, but not the way to filter through those fields. It doesn't seem to be possible for now.